# How can I retrieve POST data from a Jetty AbstractHandler handle() method?

Tags: java, rest, post, jetty

Searched SO quite a bit, but didn't see any posts that seemed to match my particular situation/question.

Using Jetty, I have a Handler class extending org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.

The handle method is as follows:

```
@Override
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                       throws IOException, ServletException {
```

I need to grab the POST data sent in the request, as if like this:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"url":"http://www.example.com"}' http://localhost:8080/`

Basically, I'm sending a POST request to my localhost with a JSON dictionary keyed on 'url'. How can I retrieve that POST data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the standard servlet features available to from the `HttpServletRequest` parameter in the [`Handler.handle()`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler.html#handle(java.lang.String,%20org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)) method.

The [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)  has 2 methods that have access to the request body.

- For text content, use [`HttpServletRequest.getReader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader())
- For binary content, use [`HttpServletRequest.getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream())

Then just use either of those 2 using standard java IO techniques.